What is the correct order for cross partial derivative?
What is the strict or correct convention for the order of partial derivatives (under the premise that partial derivatives are possible)? I was confused from time to time and couldn't find the answer in textbooks.
Wiki says, The cross partial derivative with respect to x and y is obtained by taking the partial derivative of f with respect to x, and then taking the partial derivative of the result with respect to y, to obtain
$$
\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\, \partial x} \equiv \partial \frac{\partial f / \partial x}{\partial y} \equiv \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial y} \equiv f_{xy}
$$
But as I can recall for earlier readings, the order from left to right corresponds to from inside to outside, i.e.,
$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\equiv\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$ which is not necessarily equal to $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$
So what rule shall be followed?

"...with respect to x and y..." is ambiguous. It should say "...with respect to x then y..." which they do as described. In practice, for most functions you come across, it does not matter which way round you do it

There may be no correct convention. When the order matters I think explicit is better than implicit and the rule $f_{x y} = (f_x)_y$ looks appealing.

Nearly all functions you will ever differentiate satisfy the conditions of Schwarz' and Clairaut's theorem. The counter examples are as pathological as those for functions that are differentiable only at a single point, or differentiable but not continuously differentiable.

@Kurt G.，You mentioned differentiable but not continuously differentiable where I am confused. I only know that a function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$, it must be continuous at $x_0$. Or your continuously differentiable means that its derivative is also continuous at $x_0$?

It means the latter. That any at $x_0$ differentiable function is continuous there is totally trivial.

Thanks for teaching.
